# Streaming Insert/Update using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This is regarding streaming data Insert/Update using google cloud function. I am using Salesforce as Source database and wanted to do a streaming insert/update to google BigQuery tables. My insert part is working fine but how can i able to do a update since streaming data is getting inserted into a streaming buffer first which wont allow to do DML operation for a period of 30 min or so. Any help on this will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from Google Support like below

"It is true that modifying recent data for the last 30 minutes (with an active streaming buffer) is not possible as one of the limitations of BigQuery DML operations"

One of the workaround which we can try is to copy the data from streaming table to a new table and perform any operation on that. This helped me.

Thanks
vak